# How to make a virtual USB drive?

Tags: usb-storage

I have a device which run on Linux and time to time i have to 'feed' it with data on USB. The data is around 20gb and every time need to feed different data. It takes nearly an hour to copy 20gb to USB device.

Is there a way to make few virtual USB images on PC and feed my linux device directly over USB to USB bridged cable instead of buying many USB flash drives and waisting time on copying?

Comment: How are you feeding data on USB? and why is this approach used? Why not just share the data from a network share or iso or any other approach?

Comment: Depends on the usb device and usb port and if it is usb 2 or 3 how fast the transfer will be.

Comment: Short answer is "probably not without additional hardware".  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17624815/emulate-physical-usb-device-linux